# “How to fix ‘SKIN’ fit in all size of screen”

Tags: html, css

i make this code to skin my entire website.

```css
.mainpage {
  width:85%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin:auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  border:1px solid grey;
  z-index:99999999;
}
.skin {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 0px;
  left: 50%; 
}
.skin > div {
  position: relative;
  left: -50%;
  height: 1024px;
  width: 1600px; 
}
.image-skin {
  background:url(https://hypercube.gr/skin-specs.jpg);
  position: fixed;
  width: 1600px;
  height: 1024px;
  top:-190px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainpage"><h1>main page</h1></div>

<div class="skin">
  <div>
   <a href="#">
    <div class="image-skin"> 
    </div>
   </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Its work nice when width of screen 1280px but any else screen width its broke, how can i fit right in all screen like in 1280px?
Thanks in advance 
Here's a link to [code](https://codepen.io/vachos/pen/ZgEVQy)

Comment: Are you able to modify https://hypercube.gr/skin-specs.jpg image in order to near the blue bars to the margin left and right?

Comment: @RodneySalcedo yes it’s possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not set a `width` to 1600px, you should use a percentage value, with a little modification of image that you are using as background this c
ss code can help you to achieve what you want

```css
   .mainpage {
      width:85%;
      height: 100vh;
      margin:auto;
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      border:1px solid grey;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    .skin {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0px;
      left: 50%; 
    }
    .skin > div {
      position: relative;
      left: -50%;
      height: 1024px;
      width: 1600px; 
    }
    .image-skin {
      background:url(https://hypercube.gr/skin-specs.jpg);
      position: fixed;
      /*width: 1600px;*/
      
      height: 1024px;
      /*top:-190px;*/
      width: 100%;
      left: 0;
      text-align: center;
      background-position-y: 0px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: contain;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="mainpage"><h1>main page</h1></div>

    <div class="skin">
      <div>
       <a href="#">
        <div class="image-skin"> 
        </div>
       </a>         
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes totally right i don't what can't see that. here is link work fine: .[link](https://codepen.io/vachos/pen/ZgEVQy)